# Simple responsive vertical image gallery with 80% viewheight / 100% width

Tags: css

Or so I thought that that would be easy. I wanted to keep it simple so it would work in all browsers, so no Javascript. But now I ended up with this CSS which works in Chrome/Safari/iOS but not in internet explorer, and seems to behave weird on Android as well:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 80vh;

  -o-object-fit: contain; /* These lines prevent distortion on Chrome/Safari */
  object-fit: contain;

  width: 2000px; /* This seems to be needed to make small images bigger, but creates distortion on IE */
}
```

The basic idea was to have the most simple gallery ever which works on mobile phones and in a normal browser. The idea is that images should not be bigger than 80% of the view height, and never more than 100% of the width. But still take up as much space as possible and still maintain their aspect ratio.

The idea behind 80% viewheight is that everyone notices that there are multiple pictures.

The page/content only consists of `<img><br/>` tags with images of different sizes and dimensions. Nothing exiting.

With a simple max-width/max-height this already seems to work, except that small pictures never get bigger.

How do I get this to work on all browsers? Does this simple question have a simple CSS answer?

Edit: Added a reproduction website: http://seweso.com/35225404/

Edit2: Seems like object-fit: contain; doesn't work for Internet Explorer. Which is unfortunate because it does exactly what I need.

Comment: Bad question. Read this and edit the post if you want someone helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve || http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does it need to more minimal?

Comment: Less minimal, obviously. MCVE = Minimal, **Complete and Verifiable Example**

Comment: What is the oldest version of IE you need to support?

Comment: Its for a wedding, so if it doesn't work perfectly on older browsers it's fine. No clue how many people still use IE.  Most seem to use IE11, so that would even be fine.

Comment: I can't show the url publicly, as it is a bit private and it should still be a surprise.

Comment: you want the images to be one under the other?

Comment: Yes, because I want people to scroll up/down only. So all pages are the same (some pages will have text). And there will be a footer with information on all pages. I wanted it to be simple, seems like I failed :P

Comment: you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/xp173qm8/ ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It needs to work like this: http://seweso.com/35225404/ as it does in safari/chrome. But preferably also in IE. But i'm close to doing an if (IE) then nevermind. IE11 still lags behind.

Comment: oh. i misunderstood the requirements

Comment: so i guess you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/xp173qm8/2/ then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102737/discussion-between-bulanmaster-and-wouter-schut).